# How to use the current date/time in an API call?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I have a test that makes an API call, and a required part of the body that I'm passing in is a timestamp. The whole test is working except for this last piece (if I manually set the date/time before each test execution the test succeeds).

I have been trying to set a variable like this:

```
const todaysDate = Cypress.moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS-07:00');
```

but I cannot figure out how to use this in the API call. The API parameter is formatted as such:

```
"offDateTime": "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS-07:00"
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: if the format is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` why are you using `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS-07:00`, maybe change/fiddle timezone offset before or after

Comment: What do you mean by use it in an API call? Using https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html? Or from a client app you're testing? What have you tried, and what's the specific problem with it?

Comment: My mistake, I left the "-07:00" part out. Fixed the original post.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  The timestamp is a required parameter in the call to my endpoint and it has to be in the future, so for example +1 minute from the current time and date. Yes, I am using cy.request, which I have working in other tests, the hangup here is needing the timestamp to be based off the actual current time and date.

Comment: That is not at all clear from the question, please [edit] to describe the actual problem. If you're trying to adjust the time, did you read the moment documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Well I would say just adapt the given parameter according to the api's needs.

```
    const todaysDate = Cypress.moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS-07:00');
```

How to use in the API Call depends on how you create your call and what the concrete requirements in your case are. As your API use some kind of JSON to run, it usually might look something like this.

```
        const date = new Date();
  const timestamp = date.getTime();
  const publicKey = '<publickey>';
  const privateKey = '<privateKey>'

   cy.request(`/v1/public/orders?ts=${timestamp}&apikey=${publicKey}&hash=${hash}`)
  .then((response) => {
      expect(response.body).to.have.property('offDateTime', todaysDate )
  })
```

This snipplet would state a request to an existing File on your baseUrl or an explicit given url, using `-cv.visit(url)`. If file referres to baseUrl from your cypress.json configuration file, that url would be `[baseUrl]/v1/public/orders`. The rest is like you would have set an AJAX request to this file, you'll get the response form the file and can try to catch if the expected values are in.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a future date, you can easily relay on moment.js cypress includes automatically.

**Quick example how to add future dates:**

```
    var twoDaysForward = new Cypress.moment().add(2, 'day');
    document.write(twoDaysForward.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS-07:00');
```

Same works with minutes

```
    twoDaysForward.add(minutes, 'minutes');
```